# Function that creates a input name from a string in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, input

I would like know if there is a function in CakePHP that transforms `Mymodel.Mycolumn` into `data[Mymodel][Mycolumn]`.

I know how to do this with PHP only, but I would like to know if there is a built-in CakePHP function for it.

EDIT:
I don't need the input, only the name.

Comment: What do you plan to do with that string once you've got it?

Comment: automatize some log functions

Comment: That doesn't clarify anything (a code example _would_).

Answer (score 1):

See the pretty complete [CakePHP Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html).  To use the current model:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Mycolumn');
```

Or to specify the model:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Mymodel.Mycolumn');
```

Creates:

```
<input type="text" id="MymodelMycolumn" name="data[Mymodel][Mycolumn]">
```

Comment: Hi, I don't need the input, only the name really. Thanks

Comment: `$string = "data[{$Model->name}][Mycolumn]";`

Answer (score 0):

if you're sending, you can do this:

```
 <?php 
        echo $this->Form->create('Mymodel');    
        echo $this->Form->input('Mymodel.Mycolumn', array('label' => 'add data for Mycolumn'));
        echo $this->Form->submit('submit', array('class' => 'form-submit',  'title' => 'Enter')); 
 ?>
```